# How to decode a JSON response that responds with more than just the JSON string

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am sending a cURL request to an API which returns this response:

```
string(826) "HTTP/1.1 200
Server: openresty/1.13.6.2
Date: Sat, 20 Oct 2018 18:21:54 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 562
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Sat, 20 Oct 2018 21:20:26 UTC
Cache-Control: max-age=10800
X-Cache-Status: HIT

{
    "SearchResponse": {
        "Matches": {
            "SearchMatch": [
                {
                    "Id": "43000173601",
                    "Lat": 52.4770035488100035,
                    "Lon": -1.71806745583999998,
                    "Name": "Yorkminster Drive",
                    "Modes": {
                        "Mode": "BUS_OR_COACH"
                    },
                    "TopMostParentId": "430G01736"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "43000173602",
                    "Lat": 52.4776389831399968,
                    "Lon": -1.71687080637,
                    "Name": "Yorkminster Drive",
                    "Modes": {
                        "Mode": "BUS_OR_COACH"
                    },
                    "TopMostParentId": "430G01736"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Query": "yorkminster",
        "Total": 2
    }
}
```

I want to `json_decode()` the JSON response but have no clue how to get the JSON part and ignore the annoying top part. I have tried using `explode()` but that put it into more pieces than my head could handle, any ideas would be helpful.

Here is my cURL request:

```
curl_init('api url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` from your code

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sorry, I just updated the question with my code - thought I added it, I do not have that in my code

Comment: Remove CURLOPT_HEADER from your code.

Comment: Worked like a charm! thank you so much! @LawrenceCherone

Comment: `Var_dump(json_decode(substr($str, strpos($str, "{")), true));` skip to `{` in the string.